# Differentiating an Integral with respect to a variable integration limit

Tags: integration

Suppose I have something like:

$y=\int_{-\infty}^{a}f(x)dx$

Can I differentiate $y$ with respect to $a$?

If so, are there any substitutions, transformations, etc. that I can apply?

Comment: Yes, you can. The derivative is simply $f(a)$. This is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Assuming continuity at $a$, yes, @MathematicsStudent1122.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 do you know what we call this property

Comment: @TedShifrin do you know what we call this property

Comment: Are you worrying about the integral's starting at $-\infty$? It's still the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus when $f$ is continuous. Write $\int_{-\infty}^x = \int_{-\infty}^a + \int_a^x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin thanks.